# Нужно полностью обновить SQLite базу данных при повышении версии кода приложения

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite

Имеется приложение, которое работает с локальной базой данных `SQLite`. В этой БД хранятся ссылки на файлы и ключевые слова, по которым можно найти их.

При первом запуске приложения создается БД путем парсинга xml. Все чудесно работало до тех пор, пока не встал вопрос обновления ВСЕХ записей в 2 таблицах БД.

Думал выполнить `DROP TABLE ...`, а потом создать их и наполнить в методе onUpgrade(), но при вызове `AsyncTask` из ловлю ошибку записи в БД - бд занята! <s>Нечего ломиться!</s>

Что делать нужно в такой ситуации ?

**UPD 0**

```
new LinksWordColorLoader(MyAppClass.getContext()).loadStepByStep();

содержит в себе


public LinksWordColorLoader(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        DataBase dataBase = MyAppClass.getDataBaseInstance();
        mDB = dataBase.getSQLiteDataBase();
    }

    public void loadStepByStep() {
        new LoadDataAsync().execute();
    }
```

```
// прописан в классе MyAppClass, который унаследован от Application
public static DataBase getDataBaseInstance() {
        DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();
        dataBase.openDB();
        return dataBase;
}
```

**UPD1**

```
01-11 14:28:47.410 E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ui.activity.ActivityMain}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                       Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:909)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:654)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:340)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:314)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:239)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:849)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:829)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:734)
                          at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1086)
                          at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
                          at com.database.DataBase.openDB(DataBase.java:284)
                          at com.util.app.MyAppClass.getDataBaseInstance(MyAppClass.java:22)
                          at com.database.LinksWordColorLoader.(LinksWordColorLoader.java:32)
                          at com.database.DataBase$DBManager.onUpgrade(DataBase.java:328)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)
                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
                          at com.database.DataBase.openDB(DataBase.java:284)
                          at com.app.MyAppClass.getDataBaseInstance(MyAppClass.java:22)
                          at com.ui.fragment.data.HomeFrag.onCreateView(HomeFrag.java:62)
                          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:
```

**UPD2**

```
// в классе DataBase
private DBManager mDBManager;
private SQLiteDatabase mDB;


public void openDB() {
        mDBManager = new DBManager(
                mContext,           // context
                DATABASE_NAME,      // DataBase Name
                null,        // SQLiteDataBase Factory
                DATABASE_VERSION);  // DataBase Version
        mDB = mDBManager.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void closeDB() {
        if (mDBManager != null) { mDBManager.close(); }
}

private class DBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DBManager(Context context, String dbName,
                  SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int dbVersion) {
            super(context, dbName, factory, dbVersion);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DB_LINKS_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DB_WORD_COLOR_TABLE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_LINKS_TABLE); // delete Links Table
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_WORD_COLORS_TABLE);  // delete Word-Color Table

            onCreate(db);
            new LinksWordColorLoader(MyAppClass.getContext()).loadStepByStep();
        }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71540/discussion-on-question-by-web-alex----sqlite---).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы найти решение для своего вопроса, мне пришлось переписать весь код.
Теперь все вот так:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my_database";

    private static DataBaseHelper mInstance;
    private static SQLiteDatabase myWritableDb;

    private DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static DataBaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getMyWritableDatabase() {
        if ((myWritableDb == null) || (!myWritableDb.isOpen())) {
            myWritableDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        return myWritableDb;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        MyAppLogs.show("onCreate DataBase Tables");
        db.execSQL(DB_LINKS_TABLE_CREATE); // CREATE LINK TABLES
        db.execSQL(DB_WORD_COLOR_TABLE_CREATE); // CREATE WORD-COLOR TABLE
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // удаляем таблицы
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_LINKS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_WORD_COLORS_TABLE);

        onCreate(db);
        new UpgradeDataAsync(db).execute();
    }

// далее идут определения: название таблиц, колонок, скрипты создания этих таблиц
```

**класс UpgradeDataAsync()** - отвечает за наполнение пустых таблиц данными в `AsyncTask`

```
public class UpgradeDataAsync extends AsyncTask {

    // здесь различные поля
    private SQLiteDatabase mSQLiteDB;

    public UpgradeDataAsync(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.mSQLiteDB = db;
    }

    // далее идут переопределенные методы AsyncTask: onPreExecute(), doInBackground(), и onProgressUpdate() и т.д. В которых мне и нужен был экземпляр SQLiteDatabase.

}
```